# Multiple broadcast Actions in single receiver not working After adding <data android:scheme="package" /> with PACKAGE_ADDED and PACKAGE_REMOVED

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I am creating an application which will send me events of various actions,
I have added bellow events in the single class which is working perfectly.

```
<receiver android:name=".activity.SettingsEventReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!--*************Bluetooth*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />

        <!--*************Hotspot*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED" />

        <!--*************AirplaneMode*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>

        <!--*************VolumeChange*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />

        <!--*************ChargingSettings*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />

        <!--*************Sim status changed Event*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />

        <!--*************Reboot Event*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>

    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

but whenever I do add bellow actions, I dont receive a single event

```
<!--*************Install/Uninstall Event*********************-->
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH"/>
    <data android:scheme="package" />
```

How can I overcome this issue?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the `<data>` element to the `<intent-filter>` you will only get broadcast events that match that `<data>` element. Most of the broadcast `Intent`s you've listed do not contain any data.

You can specify multiple `<intent-filter>`, like this:

```
<receiver android:name=".activity.SettingsEventReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!--*************Bluetooth*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />

        <!--*************Hotspot*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_AP_STATE_CHANGED" />

        <!--*************AirplaneMode*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>

        <!--*************VolumeChange*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />

        <!--*************ChargingSettings*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />

        <!--*************Sim status changed Event*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED" />

        <!--*************Reboot Event*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <!--*************Install/Uninstall Event*********************-->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH"/>
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```